# Obter resposta padrão se não existir no WhereIn do Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou buscando uma série de itens em um DB usando o Laravel através da função `whereIn()`.

Ao retornar, ele apresenta uma Collection com as informações encontradas, o problema acontece quando ele não acha um item, ele não apresenta nada relacionado a este item (obviamente, pois o item não existe no DB).

Existe alguma forma, no Laravel, de colocarmos uma resposta padrão nessa Collection que está sendo construída? Segue exemplo.

Como está sendo feito:

> Seja $item_ids = [1, 2, 4] // o item id 4 não existe, nesse caso.

```
$items = Item::whereIn('item_id', $item_ids)->get(['item_id', 'is_available']);
```

A resposta é assim:

```
{
  "items" : {[
    0: {
      "item_id": 1,
      "is_available": true;
    },
    1: {
      "item_id": 2,
      "is_available": true;
    }
  ]}
}
```

o item id 4 foi ignorado, pois não existe no banco, o que eu preciso é uma resposta padrão para quando não houver um item, por exemplo:

```
{
  "items" : {[
    0: {
      "item_id": 1,
      "is_available": true;
    },
    1: {
      "item_id": 2,
      "is_available": true;
    },
    2: {
      "item_id": 4,
      "is_available": false;
    },
  ]}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a mesma linha de racíocinio do @ademir-mazer-jr-nuno vou deixar uma resposta para enriquecer o post.

https://paste.laravel.io/873076f6-e386-4222-b225-44bd15b6aa97

```
$item_ids = [1, 2, 4];
 
//simulando itens do resultado do whereIn
$items = [
    [
         "item_id" =>  1,
         "is_available" =>  true
    ],
    [
         "item_id" =>  2,
         "is_available" =>  true
    ]
];
 
//simulando itens do resultado do whereIn
$itemsFromDB = collect($items);
$itemsFromDBPluck = $itemsFromDB->pluck('item_id')->toArray();
 
collect($item_ids)->map(function ($item) use ($itemsFromDB, $itemsFromDBPluck) {
    if (!in_array($item, $itemsFromDBPluck)) {
        $appendItem = [ 'item_id' => $item,'is_avaiable' => false];
        $itemsFromDB->push($appendItem);
    }
});
dump($itemsFromDB);//$itemsFromDB->toArray();
```

E usando where:

```
collect($item_ids)->map(function ($item) use ($itemsFromDB) {
    ///dump($item);
    $findItem = $itemsFromDB->where('item_id',$item);
    if ($findItem->isEmpty()) {
        $appendItem = [ 'item_id' => $item,'is_avaiable' => false];
        $itemsFromDB->push($appendItem);
    }
});
dump($itemsFromDB);//$itemsFromDB->toArray();
```

A saída de ambos exemplos será:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#268 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "item_id" => 1
      "is_available" => true
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "item_id" => 2
      "is_available" => true
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "item_id" => 4
      "is_avaiable" => false
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Boa Marcos, votei um positivo p vc pra tentar minimizar os negativos absolutamente sem fundamento que essa comunidade  do StackOverflow em Português adora. Isso daqui tá cada vez pior, nossas respostas são soluções legítimas para a questão e a própria questão está totalmente de acordo, mas aqui é avalanche de negativos ... pensando seriamente em abandonar de vez o Stack PT BR

Comment: Eu nem reclamo mais de down votes, ainda entro pra ajudar a galera pois um dia fui iniciante (claro que estou em constante aprendizado)  e gosto de compartilhar um pouco do conhecimento. Nos down votes poderiam ao menos descrever o motivo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usaria uma outra lógica, faz um map nos itens e retorna com a estrutura da coleção que precisa

```
$itemsAvaiable = Item::whereIn('item_id', $item_ids)->get(['item_id', 'is_available']);

$itemsNotAvaiable = collect($item_ids)->map(function ($item) use ($itemsAvaiable) {
    return [
        'item_id' => $item,
        'is_avaiable' => $itemsAvaiable->contains('item_id', $item)
    ];
});

$items = $itemsAvaiable->merge($itemsNotAvaiable);
```